# Android: is android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED triggered at device reboot?

Tags: android, date, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I made this broadcast receiver

```
public class DateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.i("DATE RECEIVER", "OK");
   }
}
```

registered in manifest

```
     <receiver
        android:name=".DateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

It works when device is on but if I turn it off and wait for midnight to pass, then I don't get any intent at reboot. How should I get it?

Comment: "It works when device is on" -- no, it does not, as [you have blocked anyone from sending a broadcast to it via `android:exported="false"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported).

Comment: I saw the Log when it was on

Comment: I opened system settings and manually changed time, after a second the receiver was called and log.i was printed

Comment: your link says that "the presence of at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications, so the default value is "true"."

Comment: You are overriding the default, setting it to `false`. The default will only be used if you do not specify an `android:exported` attribute at all.

Comment: then I really don't know why... try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't get this broadcast because date has NOT changed (unless i.e. there's time update after the boot). It is different but has not changed in the way that justifies this broadcast. This may be confusing but in fact it does not matter what time stamp is when device starts. As device was started it does not know if that was because of restart or it was off for 5 weeks. Broadcast will be send if time is artificially changed i.e. due to network time sync, manual time change via preferences, timezone change. Normal ticking does not count. Initial time stamp does not matter.

If you need to know date on boot, you should listen to `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

You also need to remove `android:exported="false"` or set it to `true` as otherwise it is not reachable.

Comment: you mean I'll have to store the current day in shared pref, then check if system says another day at reboot?

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve. why you care about the **fact** of date change instead of just get current stamp and apply your logic on this? in the latter case it does not matter what the reason date changed